# Objects and ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

So rather than describe what I have tried, I will just simply lay out what I am trying to do, as every method thus far has failed me, and I am sure it is something simple I am missing.

What I need to do is make an array of objects. Whether it is an arraylist that holds objects, or an object array that holds objects I do not care.

I have to make a banking program, I have 8 data fields, each set makes up an account and thus an object. I first add all 8 data fields into an object, then I have been adding that object to either an arraylist or array of objects.

My issue, is when I try to recall a specific account. Let's say I call up the arraylist or object array, when I try to call the original objects within either of those, they are empty or incompatible. It's almost as if the data just getting mushed together.

here is some code I have to help explain.

```
static ArrayList AccountList = new ArrayList();
    static Object[] User = new Object[8];
```

where I add the data into the object User

```
type = AddAccount.jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    User[0] = type;
    number = AddAccount.jTextField1.getText();
    User[1] = number;
    owner = AddAccount.jTextField2.getText();
    User[2] = owner;
    date = AddAccount.jTextField3.getText();
    User[3] = date;
    balance = AddAccount.jTextField4.getText();
    User[4] = balance;
    fee = AddAccount.jTextField5.getText();
    User[5] = fee;
    rate = AddAccount.jTextField6.getText();
    User[6] = rate;
    minBalance = AddAccount.jTextField7.getText();
    User[7] = minBalance;
       AccountList.add(counter,User);
    counter++;
```

I call the following when I want data, int selection is just referring the object I want

```
 public static void displayData(int selection) {
            int row = selection;
            Object temp = AccountList.get(selection);
            System.out.println(temp[0].toString); //<--WHY WONT THAT WORK?

        }
```

Any help appreciated, or alternative methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some issues I can note here:

1. You keep using the same `Object[]`, before each insertion you should create a new `Object[]` - otherwise you will override existing data. [remember, the `ArrayList` contains references, if you modify an object in it, it will be modified in the `ArrayList` as well.
2. You need to cast `temp` to an `Object[]` - or even better, declare `AccountList` as `ArrayList<Object[]>`
3. After all of it is done - it should be `toString()`, and not `toString` [it is a method]

Not related, but important for readability: in java, the convention is that variables are starting with lower-case characters. It helps fellow programmers understand when reading `accountList` and not `AccountList` that it is a variable, and not a class.

Also, as @GuillaumePolet mentioned, you might want to reconsider the desing, instead of using an `Object[]`, and storing it in the `ArrayList`, you can build your own class [`MyBankAccount` for examples] with 8 fields, and have `AccountList` of type `ArrayList<MyBankAccount>`. You will find it much easier to follow the logic and maintain your code this way!

Comment: Yeah, and also in the same not-related but it would help, Java is an OO language, so instead of modeling objects with Object[], you could actually create a new Class with those 8 properties, that would be a lot better

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: I agree, I was focused in finding the errors, and did not mention the design issue. However, C is no OO language, and I'd follow this line anyway by creating a `struct` :). I editted the answer and added this issue as well. thanks.